# Subnet mask for 192.168.1.7/30

Tags: ip, cisco, router, subnet, mask

I want to create two IP addresses, 192.168.1.0/30
and 192.168.1.5.

Adding the first IP for the router port returns this error "Bad mask /30 for address 192.168.1.7":

```
Router>en
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#in
Router(config)#interface fa 0/0
Router(config-if)#ip add
Router(config-if)#ip address 192.168.1.7 255.255.255.252
Bad mask /30 for address 192.168.1.7
Router(config-if)#
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Answer (score 7):

With `192.168.1.7 255.255.255.252`, the addresses range from `192.168.1.4 - 192.168.1.7`.

`192.168.1.4` is the network address.
`192.168.1.7` is the broadcast address.

You cannot apply either of those 2 addresses as an interface address.

With that range & mask, your only usable IP addresses are `192.168.1.5` & `192.168.1.6`.

For `192.168.1.0/30`, the address range is `192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.3`.

`192.168.1.0` is the network address.
`192.168.1.3` is the broadcast address.

The only usable IP addresses are `192.168.1.1` & `192.168.1.2`.

Answer (score 3):

/30 uses the lower two bits as the host part. As with all IPv4 subnets, the all-zero ..00 address and the all-one ..11 (subnet directed broadcast) address aren't usable for hosts.

192.168.1.7 means 000001**11** in the last octet, so that's the directed broadcast address for the 192.168.1.4/30 subnet. Usable for hosts are only 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.1.6.

192.168.1.0/30 is an adjacent subnet with the usable addresses 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2.

For point-to-point links you should prefer /31 subnets where both addresses are usable for hosts and there's no (useless) broadcast and no 50% address waste.

Comment: Yeah, prefer to use /31